# Disappearing left side of `aligned`

Tags: amsmath, alignment, bugs

The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
[E^dx,y]&=E^k[E^{d-k}x,y]-kE^{k-1}[E^{d-k}x,Ey]\\
&+\binom k2E^{k-2}[E^{d-k}x,E^2y]-...\\
&+(-1)^j\binom kjE^{k-j}[E^{d-k}x,E^jy]+...\\
&+(-1)^{k-1}kE[E^{d-k}x,E^{k-1}y]+(-1)^k[E^{d-k}x,E^ky].
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

produces (for me)

[image]

As you see, the left-hand side `[E^dx,y]` of `aligned` has disappeared.

Does anybody know the reason, and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: put `\relax` after `\begin{aligned}` to stop the `[` being taken as an optional argument

Comment: why use `\[\begin{aligned}` here rather than `\begin{align*}` ?

Comment: also help to add `\usepackage{mathtools}` in preamble of your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, this works! Maybe make this an answer? The reason I use `aligned` is that I want to have a common tag for the whole display, put midway along the vertical

Comment: OK if you'd used `\begin{equation}` rather than `\[` so the equation number appeared I wouldn't have asked:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that would be more understandable. Maybe I replace the example with that

Comment: doesn't matter really, the issue is just with aligned (we have considered fixing this, but there are some compatibility issues your `[E^dx,y]` is "clearly" intended to be part of the formula, but if it had been `[t]` then it may have been _intended_ to specify top alignment and if we change things to make it typeset `[t]` then documents may break....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see... OK I leave it as it is. Btw do you think the [tag:bugs] tag is relevant here?

Comment: It's a documented feature (it also must be a duplicate but a bit hard to search for)  so normally bug wouldn't be appropriate except this feature isn't that great so we may change it... ah found what I was looking for https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/5

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, good to know! Well, it is marked as a bug there... :)

Comment: I know (may have been me that did that:-)

Comment: @Zarko nice suggestion too - `mathtools` is a great package!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour but not that great and may change in a future release see

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/5

The `[...]` is taken as an optional argument, so you can "hide" it with `\relax`

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}\relax
[E^dx,y]&=E^k[E^{d-k}x,y]-kE^{k-1}[E^{d-k}x,Ey]\\
&+\binom k2E^{k-2}[E^{d-k}x,E^2y]-...\\
&+(-1)^j\binom kjE^{k-j}[E^{d-k}x,E^jy]+...\\
&+(-1)^{k-1}kE[E^{d-k}x,E^{k-1}y]+(-1)^k[E^{d-k}x,E^ky].
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```